Иногда долгие XHR-запросы. После перезапуска баузера Chrome проблема пропадает
Периодически сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой: XHR-запросы начинают очень долго выполняться. Обычно на них отводится меньше секунды, но бывают отрезки времени, когда они выполняются крайне долго (20-30 секунд).
При этом замечаю, что если перезапустить браузер (chrome), то запросы и сам сайт начинают нормально загружаться (меньше секунды). Еще, в момент этих "долгих загрузок" я параллельно обращался к сайту с другого браузера (firefox) и там все загружалось нормально. В целом очень странное поведение и причину я пока не нашел...
Никаких сложных вычислений в момент запроса нет. Нагрузки на процессор или утечки памяти на сервере и на клиенте не наблюдал в этот момент.
Я использую nodejs и делал console.log перед самой отправкой данных:
    //const filteredLevels = данные из БД...

   console.log(filteredLevels) // console.log срабатывает в консоли быстро, но ответа в XHR-запросе в браузере еще долго нет.

    return response.status(200).json({
        success: 1,
        levels: filteredLevels,
    });

Прилагаю скриншоты с нормальной загрузкой и медленной загрузкой из dev tools chorme:


Еще я подозреваю CloudFlare, у меня трафик через них идет и может быть они являются причиной данной проблемы, но я пока не знаю как это проверить...
На сеть тоже нет особой нагрузки в "моменты зависаний". Исходящий трафик примерно 10 MiB/s (84 Mbps).

Да, все-таки был виноват CloudFlare: отключение в CloudFlare протокола HTTP/3 помогло ускорить сайт в моем случае.

Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — из очереди проверок

@ksa, почему же не является?

@Qwertiy, на мой взгляд это больше комментарий...

@ksa, странный взгляд...
